# Would it be illegal to display a Facebook page in an an Android application?

Tags: facebook, web-scraping

I am working on an application that needs to allow users to access the Facebook posts of their friends. However, the Facebook API does not allow access to the posts of other people.

I am aware that scraping the users web page for the data is illegal, and was curious if it would be unethical to simply display the Facebook page with the relevant information, rather than to scrape the data and integrate it directly in my app?

I don't see why this would be illegal, but I also don't see much of a difference between just displaying the web page, and reading the web page for the relevant data.

Comment: No, as long as you just show a page without manipulating it or trying to read info from it, that would be fine. (The question would just be, what purpose your app actually serves then ... because as a user, I could pretty much get the same result by using my browser or the FB mobile app …)

Comment: Hm... Let's say you were to zoom into a certain aspect of the web page in order to more effectively display the specific part you are interested in, would it be considered "manipulation"? And where would I even look for information on something like this?